# Как получить id у текущего блока?

Tags: html, jquery

Как забирать `train_id` текущего блока при клике?

```
$("#tab-item-body").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('train_id'));
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а в чём вопрос-то? у тебя написано как забирать. вот так вот, как у тебя написано. по this attr

Comment: В html нельзя повторять один и тот же `id` у разных тегов. Ваш html-код некорректен — исправьте сперва id, а уже потом разбирайтесь с train_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".tab-item-body").click(function () {
  console.log($(this).attr('train_id'));
});
```

выбрать нужно по классу а не по id

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#tab-item-body").click(function(ev) {
    console.log($(ev.target).attr('train_id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div train_id="kek" id="tab-item-body">
Click me
</div>
```

P.S. id у элементов должен быть уникальным.